# Ampscript appears on Subscribers Subscription Center page

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Apologies if this has been asked before!
Our subscribers see AMPscript on their Subscription Center page(please see below).

[image]

When we send an email with SFMC we paste AMPScript into the Sender Information\From Name field. 
The link to the **SFMC** Subscription Center is in a Custom Footer but uses the standard AMPScript function(I believe): %%subscription_center_url%%

When sending the email, the email from name is correctly the name of our Outlet.
I just want the text at the bottom of the Subscription Center to read:
*If you wish to unsubscribe from ALL publications from Marketing, check the box and click the update button below.*

*** RESULT ***
The Advanced Team(support) had a tool (as suggested) to very quickly amend BRAND TAGS. As this is a permanent change to the page all previous emails have now been fixed. I'm very impressed with SalesForce and their support(you just need to know what to ask for). So thankyou for your help!

Can anyone offer any ideas?
Many Thanks for your help
Mark

Comment: I am not sure exactly what you are looking for, can you clarify? Are you saying that the ampscript is not working and just displaying as text in email or in subscription center? Or are you looking to create a custom footer in the email with a check box?

Comment: Is the custom Subscription Center page hosted in SFMC?

Comment: Hi Gortonington, Thanks for your help. Hopefully you can see the AMPScript is just shown as it is in the Subscription Center. The problem(possibly) is that the SenderInformation\FromName information can't be interpreted at a later point. I think it's standard functionality to place AMPScript in this field(I learned how to do it on an SF course). When sending the email a Subscriber might be signed up against several outlets - they could get the email from two outlets each email will be From the OutletName stored in an Outlets DataExtension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's the stock preference center, you contact SFMC Support and have them change the text with what they call `Brand Tags`.  It's not documented anywhere (that I know of), but the SFMC Support reps have a back-end utility to make simple verbiage changes like this.

Comment: That's brilliant - thanks very much for your help. Despite logging two calls and contacting our rep this hasn't been suggested.

Comment: There are many other things like this -- special business rules, hidden data views, etc.  Please report back after you've had a chance to contact SFMC Support again.

Comment: Thanks for your help - it's been forwarded on to the Advanced team(not heard of them before). When I know more I'll update. BTW for SF to create a Custom Subscription Centre the cost was £1000(just so we can get a small wording change)!

Comment: Yeah, preferences centers are the one thing that's stuck in the dark ages with SFMC.  Doesn't surprise me about the cost.